# How can I convert UPS API integration from Soap to Rest API? Anybody has one to one object mapping?

Tags: rest, soap, shipping-method, ups-api

I'm converting the integration of UPS API from soap to rest API.
Anyone has done this before!

Answer (score 0):

I just did it last week for an old C# ASP 4.8 .NET framework web site.  Are you still having issues?  I had to figure out some oddball stuff due to JsonConverter's not being available(even though that restriction was only supposed to be for VB.NET) and due to some of the garbage UPS returns(strings for documented arrays, empty strings rather than not include or nulls, etc)